# dnsmasq without dns functionality

Tags: server, dns, dnsmasq

So, I'm trying to run `dnsmasq` as a PXE-only server. For this, I'm trying to disable dnsmasq's DNS functionality. I've put the following line in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
port=0
```

However, when starting `dnsmasq`, it registers itself as DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

This is apparently done by `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq`. The file contains some code to disable this resolvconf behavior by having `lo` in `$DNSMASQ_EXCEPT`. But I can't figure out how I am suppose to put it in there (without editing the file).

I tried putting the following line in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
except-interface=lo
```

But this doesn't help. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

*Update:* I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Just add the following line to `/etc/default/dnsmasq`:

```
DNSMASQ_EXCEPT=lo
```

That's it.

Comment: Why would this work? Won't this just disable dnsmasq on the local interface, and still enable DNS on other interfaces?

Comment: @phihag This works because of `port=0` (as stated in the question)

Answer (score 9):

Start it with `-p0`. You need to add this option to `/etc/default/dnsmasq`:

```
DNSMASQ_OPTS="-p0"
```

Info about port is from [dnsmasq(8) man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)

```
-p, --port=<port>
Listen on <port> instead of the standard DNS port (53). Setting this to zero 
completely disables DNS function, leaving only DHCP and/or TFTP.
```